# how can I embed ruby code in textile markup?

Tags: ruby, textile, redcloth

how can I embed ruby code in textile markup?

Here's an example of what I'm working with:

```
  doc = RedCloth.new <<-EOD
    h1. Images

    "backward":[choose previous image...1.png] "forward":[choose next image...3.png]

    !http://www.w3.org/Icons/valid-html401!:http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer
  EOD
```

Answer (score 0):

The below should work:

```
doc = RedCloth.new <<-EOD
    #{h1. Images}

    #{"backward":[choose previous image...1.png]} #{"forward":[choose next image...3.png]}

    #{!http://www.w3.org/Icons/valid-html401!:http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer}
EOD
```